# C - removing duplicates from an array and storing those duplicates in another array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, integer

I have an array called `allnumbersarray` and I need to remove the duplicates of the array and store them in another called `uniqueprimes`. The `allnumbersarray` is composed of prime numbers. When I try to use an if - else if statement, the output gets jumbled and a lot of the elements turn to 0 and aren't sorted anymore. Here is what I've tried, not sure what to change:

```
int temp[], temp2[];
int removeDuplicates()
    {
        int n, j =0;
        temp[n];
        temp2[n];

        // Start traversing elements

        for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++){

            // If current element is not equal
            // to next element then store that
            // current element
            if (allnumbersarray[i] != allnumbersarray[i+1]){
                temp[j++] = allnumbersarray[i];
            }
            else if(allnumbersarray[i] == allnumbersarray[i+1])
                temp2[j++] = allnumbersarray[i];

        }
        // Store the last element as whether
        // it is unique or repeated, it hasn't
        // stored previously
        temp[j++] = allnumbersarray[n-1];

        // Modify original array
        for (int i=0; i<j; i++){
            allnumbersarray[i] = temp[i];
        }

        printf("\n\nprimes array with duplicates removed:\n");
          for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
              printf("%d\n", allnumbersarray[i]);


        return j;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not created an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — which is a problem.  Some of the following criticism might be irrelevant if the code presented was an MCVE.

There are too many global variables in the code fragment (`temp`, `temp2`), and also not enough (you've not shown how `allnumbersarray[]` is defined).  Use arguments to functions to pass data.

You say you have:

```
int temp[], temp2[];
int removeDuplicates()
    {
        int n, j =0;
        temp[n];
        temp2[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
```

You don't show where `temp` and `temp2` are defined with a size — this line should have an `extern` in front of it.  (I'm not sure why you don't use `temp1` and `temp2`, but that's a common idiosyncrasy.)

The function isn't defined with a prototype; use `int removeDuplicates(void)` to indicate that it should be called with no arguments.  As it stands, code in the same file could write `removeDuplicates(3.14, "astronomy");` and the compiler is not obliged to spot the discrepancy because the function definition does not give a prototype for the function.

You have an uninitialized variable `n` inside the function; it's value is indeterminate.  For some unexplained reason, you have `temp[n];` and `temp2[n];`, statements which read from indeterminate locations in (or, more likely, outside) the dubiously declared arrays.  The compiler might remove these references, if you're lucky, since they don't affect the computation.  But they are misguided twice — once because they do nothing and once because they use the uninitialized variable to index the arrays.

You then use this uninitialized variable `n` as a bound for your main `for` loop.  This is not going to end happily.  You never use the values carefully stored in `temp2`.

I think you need to redesign your function thoroughly.  For example, you might use:

```
 int removeDuplicates(int *n_values, int *values, int *dups)
 {
```

where `*n_values` is the number of entries in the source array (`values`), which becomes one of the output arrays.  It's passed by reference so you can identify to the calling function how many unique entries there are in the `values` array after the duplicate removal is complete (use `int n = *n_values;` near the start, and `*n_values = …new size…;` at the end).  The `dups` array is equivalent to your `temp2`.  It is assumed to be 'big enough' (which is actually a dangerous assumption).  The function will directly return the number of entries in `dups`, like the current function would if it were written correctly.

Somewhere along the line, with the current scheme, you have to copy the unique values from the source array (`values`) into spare space, simply so you can copy it back later.  A better algorithm steps through the source array with two indexes, the current read position and the current write position.  When you find an adjacent duplicate, you increment the read position without incrementing the write position. This means you end up not needing the `temp` array at all.

You also same the code 'removes duplicates' but the algorithm only looks for adjacent duplicates.  If you had an input list `(int[]){ 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 3, 11, 11, 13, 17, 19, 11 }` (that's a [compound literal](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5)), your code would not spot the third 3 nor the third 11.  It isn't clear whether that's a problem — it may be that the duplicates can only occur adjacent to each other, in which case you don't have to be as complicated in your analysis as you do if duplicates need not be adjacent.

This at least gives you some things to think about.

Next time, please make sure you post a more complete MCVE; what you've presented is too minimal for comfort.  And avoid global variables like the plague they are.  Most functions should have parameters to identify what they're going to work on.